# Upper bound for the integral $\int_{|x| \leq a} \frac{dx}{(1 + |x|)^{1 + \epsilon} \sqrt{a - x}} $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Consider the integral $ I_{a} := \int_{|x| \leq  a} \frac{dx}{(1 + |x|)^{1 + \epsilon}  \sqrt{a - x}}$, where $\varepsilon >0$ where $ a > 0$. It is known in the literature that

$$ (i) \qquad \int_{|x| \leq  a} \frac{dx}{(1 + |x|)^{1 - \varepsilon }  \sqrt{a - x}}  \leq c \frac{1}{(1 + a)^{1/2 - \varepsilon}},$$

$$ (ii) \qquad \int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} \frac{dx}{(1 + |x|)^{1 + \epsilon}  |\sqrt{a - x}|} \leq c \frac{1}{(1 + a)^{1/2}}.$$

My question  is the following: There exist $c > 0$ such that $$ I_{a} \leq c \frac{1}{(1 + a)^{1/2 + \varepsilon}} \; ? $$

I've already tried to do some manipulations to take advantage of the good decay given by the integral (i) and the fact that
$(1 + |x|)^{1 + \varepsilon}$ has  exponent $1 + \varepsilon > 1 - \varepsilon$, but I was unsuccessful. Any help will be welcome!